# Eclipse executa o xml buildfile do ANT 2 vezes, mesmo mandando executar apenas uma vez

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

No netbeans, após algumas pesquisas, consegui editar o arquivo `build.xml` de modo a personalizar a forma como a IDE gerava meu jar e meu arquivo manifest. Tive que migrar uns projetos para o eclipse, e até achei a opção de construir jar,  mas preciso construir meu jar com algumas informações personalizadas.

Adicionei o arquivo `build.xml` como um *ANT buildfile* no meu projeto no eclipse, mas quando mando executá-lo, a IDE executa 2x, gerando 2 arquivos jars de uma vez.

Segue meu arquivo `build.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="GerOficios" default="makejar" basedir='.'>

    <target name="makejar">

        <property file="version_info.properties" />

        <property name="application.title" value="GerOficios_v6" />

        <property name="main.class" value="com/dfmachado/geroficios/View/ListaDeOficiosUI" />

        <buildnumber file="build.num" />

        <property name="build.version.num" value="${version.number}.${build.number}" />

        <tstamp>
            <format property="TODAY" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />
        </tstamp>

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="GerOficios ${build.version.num}" />

        <property name="store.dir" value="store" />
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar" />

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}" />

        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}" />

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" basedir="bin" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
                <attribute name="SplashScreen-Image" value="com/dfmachado/geroficios/View/image/minerva.png" />

                <attribute name="Build-OS" value="${os.name} version ${os.version} on ${os.arch}" />
                <attribute name="Java-Version" value="${javac.source}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${application.title}" />
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${build.version.num}" />
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA" />
        </zip>
        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" />

    </target>

</project>
```

Apenas pra salientar, o eclipse gera o jar do jeito que gerava no netbeans, o problema é o xml ser executado 2 vezes e gerar 2 jars, mesmo eu dando comando apenas uma vez, como pode ser visto no print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após sugestão do @VictorStafusa, executei o ant via linha de comando no mesmo projeto e foi criado apenas um arquivo, aparentemente o problema é alguma configuração no eclipse, mas eu não consegui localizar nenhuma até agora.

Comment: O Netbeans gera apenas uma vez ou também gera duas?

Comment: `<property file="version_info.properties" />` - O que há nesse arquivo de propriedades?

Comment: @VictorStafusa só um versionamento que fiz manualmente, só tem uma linha : `version.number=?.?.?`.

Comment: Se você executar o ant via linha de comando, o que acontece?

Comment: @VictorStafusa vou ser sincero, não faço a minima ideia de como faz isso :/ to pesquisando como que faz aqui e já posto a saida.

Comment: Abre o prompt, vai na pasta do seu projeto e digita `ant`. Se o prompt disser que não conhece o `ant`, coloque-o no PATH, feche o prompt, abra de novo e repita o processo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa que estranho, via linha de comando cria somente um, o problema deve ser com o eclipse então.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após [perguntar no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40634029/5524514) em simultâneo, consegui localizar a causa do problema. Basicamente era ter adicionado o arquivo buildfile do *ant* nas configurações do *Builder* do projeto. Como o eclipse, por padrão, compila o projeto automaticamente(até para agilizar a execução do mesmo), ao mandar executar o *ant* em separado, ele também executava a referencia ao buildfile que adicionei no *builder*.

A solução dada foi remover/desativar o arquivo build.xml das configurações do Builder do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E pra chegar ai o caminho é:

> Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Builders